Is SeleniumBasic workable project now with VBA?
Project https://florentbr.github.io/SeleniumBasic/ updated 9 years ago. I have installed fresh version of https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases (I place PATH of geckodriver to system PATH), also FF I have in fresh version. AI support get me this pattern to call SeleniumBasic:
Dim driver As New Selenium.FirefoxDriver
  Dim FirefoxOptions As Object
  Set FirefoxOptions = CreateObject("Selenium.Firefox.FirefoxOptions")
  FirefoxOptions.SetBinary("C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe")  'Example path; adapt as needed
  driver.SetCapability "moz:firefoxOptions", "{""args"": [""-headless""]}", FirefoxOptions  'Optional: For headless mode
  driver.Start "firefox", "D:\Geckodriver\geckodriver.exe" , "https://www.example.com" ' Specify path here
  driver.Get "your-website-url"
  driver.FindElementById("elementId").SendKeys "your value" & Chr(13) 'Using ID
  driver.FindElementByName("elementName").SendKeys "your value" & Chr(13) 'Using name
  driver.FindElementByCss("input[type='text']").SendKeys "your value" & Chr(13) 'Using CSS selector
  driver.Quit
End Sub

Unfortunately, even simplest attempt to call SeleniumBasic get me error - "Firefox failed to open listening port 127.0.0.1:xxx"

It something wrong with my tuning (security or something other) or this is not workable project at all?

If Firefox actually located at the location you say it is?

Yes, thanks, I checked again now. What I can check additionally, do you have any ideas?

The top is the sample you followed, right?  Your actual code doesn't do all of the setup steps.  You haven't set the binary name, and you haven't done driver.Start.

code version on top don't working, this is advice from AI, I try to use it and received only mistake that I use wrong parameter. Therefore I try to used simplest version (close to bottom on the screen) - and this version is also failed. But what mistake you see in full version and in simplified version? I can not understand, sorry...

I still use selenium wth VBA. Most of my projects I use with Chrome.
A few important things:

make sure your webdriver is compatible with your version (for chrome: https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/)
if you have to update, the chromedriver you need to substitute should be in "C:\Users[your user]\AppData\Local\SeleniumBasic"
make sure you checked "selenium type library"
tools>references

Usually, I just use:
Dim bot As New WebDriver
bot.Start "chrome", weburl
bot.Get "site"
bot.FindElementById("elementId").SendKeys "your value" 

if you send the website that you are trying to login, I can help mapping the elements
Note: DO NOT share your login and password
